# Mongo db not starting

Tags: mongodb

Whenever I try to use start mongo db using the command "mongo" it shows me the following error. I have removed the mongod.lock file from the /var/mongo/ directory but still I  am facing this error.

```
    MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
    connecting to: test
    Fri May  2 11:36:02.667 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at                src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
    exception: connect failed.
```

Can anyone suggest me some steps to restart my mongo db.

Comment: You need to start the server (mongod), the mongo command starts the shell that wants connect to the server (127.0.0.1:27017)

Comment: You cannot access `mongo` if you haven't started `mongod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mongod server might not be running or may be running on a different port.

Look for mongod info here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/.

Also check if you can do a ping using command line.

ping 127.0.0.1:27017

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

This problem could be solved by the below mentioned 4 steps

1) Remove .lock file

sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

2) repair the mongodb

mongod –repair

3) start the mongodb

sudo service mongodb start

4) start the mongo client

mongo